# How to handle PHP form(URL) properly with HTML, CSS using checkbox?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I'm having trouble with my code especially with the form. This is my HTML code.

```
<form action="index.php/homepage/deleteSelected" method="POST">
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete Selected">
                        <table align="center">
                            <thead>
                                <!-- <th>Action</th> -->
                                <th>Selection</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Date Created</th>
                                <th>Options</th>
                            </thead>
                            <!-- CODE HERE -->
                    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($student_records as $row){?>
                        <?php if(($counter % 2) == 0){?>
                            <tbody class='even'>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->firstname;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->dateCreated;?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href='index.php/homepage/toEditStudent?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>'><button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>
                                    <a href='index.php/homepage/deleteStudent?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>'><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                                </td>
                            </tbody>
                        <?php }else{?>
                            <tbody class='odd'>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->firstname;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->dateCreated;?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href='index.php/homepage/toEditStudent?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>'><button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>
                                    <a href='index.php/homepage/deleteStudent?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>'><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                                </td>
                            </tbody>
                        <!-- END CONDITION -->
                        <?php }?>
                    <?php $counter++; ?>
                    <!-- END FOREACH -->
                    <?php }?>
                        </form>
```

Everytime I click the edit button, the form receives it. It must go to index.php/homepage/toEditStudent not index.php/homepage/deleteSelected. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Everytime I click the edit button, the form receives it. It must go to index.php/homepage/toEditStudent not index.php/homepage/deleteSelected.

Your form's `action` attribute is `index.php/homepage/deleteSelected`.

You need to change the action to `index.php/homepage/toEditStudent`.

**Example:**

```
<form action="index.php/homepage/toEditStudent" method="POST">
```

Comment: It must not replace the url of the form sir. They have different purpose. The form is for the checkbox and the edit student is for editing.

Comment: What Jon put makes sense to me at least... But maybe post a live link sample with the exact error messages to clear up the confusion.